# Routing Information Protocol number of hops

Tags: networking, routes

Can anyone explain me, why is the subnet z seven hops away from the router D (and not 3 hops)? Which ones are counted? Please see picture below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I believe the 'break' in the image means "any number of routers exist here."